# SQL logic and/or PHP application w/ multiplication & addition (am I taking the right approach or all wrong?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working out some psuedo code for an application problem. I would like some advice on if **Am I even remotely on the right track here or am I going about this all wrong?**

**I have 3 entry values for query:**

*Applicant Age

Spouse Age

Number of Children*

I have one rate in my rates table for each of the above values. For example, for Applicant Age > 65, I have rate $50.00. And Spouse Age >= 18 or <= 64, I have rate $40.00. Children have their own rate the same way, but there can be multiple children.

**Here is the breakdown of my problem:**

1. There is one record per applicant type (applicant, spouse and children). Each type has its own rate.
2. I need to return a **total rate** result within the confines of SQL (this is what I am hoping for), so I can build this into my existing query. So essentially I am trying to create a "magically appearing" record based on some math within the SQL. In other words, there is no record in my rates table that would contain this result amount, it would be calculated within the confines of SQL.

**Real example:** appliant_age = 24 (rate $50.00), spouse_age = 20(rate $40.00), number_of_children = 3(rate $20 x 3(number entered) rate $60.00). Total rate = $150.00.

A "magic result" record should be created which would just be built into my standard SQL results (which is already existing and working). And based on my example, it would be $150.00. And I should also be able to pass this value to my script from the query.

My main rates table (w/ applicable fields) is set up like:

```
CREATE TABLE `rates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ...
  `monthly_cost` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `age_id` int(11) NOT NULL, // e.g. 0-17 (child), 18-65 (adult), 65+ (elder) etc...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

NO I AM NOT LOOKING FOR ANYONE TO WRITE CODE FOR ME. JUST NEED SOME GUIDANCE ON WHICH IS THE BEST LOGICAL APPROACH TO THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: Voting to move to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ because this is a conceptual question.

Comment: DaveRandom, I think my question is more on the lines of which SQL function or approach can solve this problem. And is this possible with SQL (if so what is the technical term for doing such). Did you read my full thread?

Comment: Are all your variables independent? Meaning, does applicant age rate get affected at all by spouse age or number of children? And does spouse age rate get affected by applicant age or number of children? etc

Comment: Yes. All values are independent.

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want code, but code is the easiest way to express my guidance for you...

Assuming that the applicant, spouse and children are related by a single id (`application_id`), there could be a table with the following fields, probably more...

```
application_id | applicant_type_id | applicant_id | age
       1                 1                 1         24
       1                 2                 2         20
       1                 3                 3          9
       1                 3                 4          7
       1                 3                 5          6
```

Then another table with the rates...

```
applicant_type_id | inclusive_age | exclusive_age | rate
        1                18              25          50
        1                25              35          60
        1                35              45          70
        1                45              55          80
        1                55              65          90
        1                65              200        100
        2                18              25          40
        2                25              35          50
        2                35              45          60
        2                45              55          70
        2                55              65          80
        2                65              200         90
        3                 0              2            0
        3                 2              6           10
        3                 6             10           20
        3                10             14           30
        3                14             18           40
```

The query would be something like...

```
SELECT
  applicant.application_id,
  SUM(rate.rate)             AS total_rate
FROM
  applicant
INNER JOIN
  rate
    ON  rate.applicant_type_id  = applicant.applicant_type_id
    AND rate.inclusive_age     <= applicant.age
    AND rate.exclusive_age     >  applicant.age
GROUP BY
  applicant.application_id
```

Comment: Dems, thanks for the detailed example. I'm trying out some various ways of doing this and your idea is useful and appealing.

Answer (score 0):

If ..

> Children have their own rate the same way, but there can be multiple children.

Then your concept needs more detail. You need the age of each child as the rate can depends on it.

For 0-n children per applicant you create an additional table and connect it by foreign key in a n:1 relationship to the applicant. Table layout could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE applicant (
  applicant_id integer PRIMARY KEY
 ,applicant    text NOT NULL
 ,age          integer NOT NULL
 ,spouse_age   integer NOT NULL -- 0 for "no spouse"
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  child_id     integer PRIMARY KEY
, applicant_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES applicant (applicant_id)
, age          integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rate (
  rate_id integer PRIMARY KEY
, type    text NOT NULL        -- 'a' .. applicant, 's' .. spouse, 'c' .. child
, age_min integer NOT NULL
, age_max integer NOT NULL
, amount  integer NOT NULL
);
```

You would enforce that rates are **mutually exclusive** per type, so you never get more than one row for any type of any age. Also, **no** rate for spouse of age 0.

Then the query could look like this:

```
SELECT a.application_id
     , a.applicant
     , COALESCE(ra.amount, 0)
     + COALESCE(rs.amount, 0)
     + COALESCE(rc.amount, 0) AS total_amount
FROM   applicant AS a
LEFT   JOIN rate AS ra ON  r.type = 'a'
                       AND a.age BETWEEN ra.age_min AND ra.age_max
LEFT   JOIN rate AS rs ON  r.type = 's'
                       AND a.spouse_age BETWEEN rs.age_min AND rs.age_max
LEFT   JOIN (
       SELECT c.application_id, sum(r.amount) AS amount
       FROM   child AS c
       LEFT   JOIN rate AS r ON  r.type = 'c'
                             AND c.age BETWEEN rc.age_min AND rc.age_max
       GROUP  BY c.applicant_id
       ) AS rc ON rc.applicant_id = a.applicant_id
```

The subquery sums up the variable number of children before joining to the applicant.
`LEFT JOIN` allows for "no spouse" or "no children".